Async method in foreach doesn't return JSON result data when await Task.WhenAll(listOfTasks) is used
var reqs = History.OrderByDescending(m => m.DateFiled).Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize);

// Use a List instead of an array
var rowsObj = new List<object>(); 

List<Task<object[]>> listOfTasks = new List<Task<object[]>>();

// Start all async tasks
foreach (var req in reqs) 
{
    listOfTasks.Add(rr.ObjectRowsAsync(req, rowsObj));
}

try 
{
    await Task.WhenAll(listOfTasks);
} 
catch (Exception ex) 
{
    // Handle error (log it or return a meaningful error message)
    return Json(new { error = ex.Message }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

var result = new JsonResult 
                 {
                     Data = new 
                            {
                                total = totalPages,
                                page = page,
                                records = totalRecords,
                                rows = rowsObj
                            },
                     JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
                 };

return result;

The idea was to use async on a method that has foreach loop and returns array of object.
When await Task.WhenAll(listOfTasks) is used, the action doesn't return any JSON result data, but when I commented it out, the action passes the data properly, what's the best practice here?
And how can I use a breakpoint on async methods, it doesn't trigger. Or is there any way to see what's happening?
I read a lot of stack threads about async uses, even the interesting ForEachAsync and await foreach in higher versions.

The code did not show which ORM to query data. But I know that ORM operations is not thread safe almost, for example, EF does cannot execute two multiple query operations concurrently.

Show ObjectRowsAsync method. Be aware that List<T> not thread safe.

Please fix code formatting. It's unreadable on the mobile phone.

"the action doesnt return any jsonresult data" What does it return?  Does it throw an exception?  Run forever?  Return null?
